# Embed a media player with JRE1.5

Tags: java, java-native-interface, vlc, jmf, jvlc

I am trying to embed a media player into a jpanel but having not much luck as my frame work is a legacy one (running windows XP and jre 1.5).

I very much wish to use vlcj but as it turns out it minimally has to have jre6 hence I am very much stuck. I have yet to try jmf but I am turned off by the formats supported. Does anyone have a good solution? Or should I attempt to build the vlcj in jre1.5 using jni?

Comment: Why is that machine using a Java version release more than a decade ago? I would not expect to see much enthusiasm to fix things for a JRE that's a decade (over 12 years) out of date.

Comment: Yeah, tell me about it... "Legacy" systems. I tried java mf and all it shows is a pink screen. Furthermore had to convert to readable format for the media player to run.